# Build a call to get expression for do.call execution

Tags: r, classification, do.call

Giving this example:

```
lstParams <- list()
lstParams$formula <- as.formula("Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length")                         
lstParams$data <- substitute(iris)
lstParams$distribution <- "bernoulli"

mdl <- do.call("gbm", lstParams)
mdl
gbm(formula=Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, distribution="bernoulli", 
    data=iris)
# A gradient boosted model with bernoulli loss function.
# 100 iterations were performed.
# There were 2 predictors of which 0 had non-zero influence.
```

I can get the call to `gbm` function by :

```
mdl$call
gbm(formula=Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, distribution="bernoulli", 
    data=iris)
```

Since some error can happen in: `mdl<-do.call("gbm",lstParams)` (e.g some NAs found in the target variable or wrong formula):

```
lstParams <- list()
lstParams$formula <- as.formula("Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Lengthx")                        
lstParams$data <- substitute(iris)
lstParams$distribution <- "bernoulli"

mdl <- do.call("gbm", lstParams)
# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Petal.Lengthx' not found
```

**I would like to get the call to `gbm` function in advance** in order to debug it.

Is there any way to get that call before the execution?
Thanks

Comment: You could get it as `as.call(c(as.name("gbm"), lstParams))`, but I don't see why you want that.  Why not just run `debug(gbm)` before doing the call, and you can single step through it?

Comment: Thanks a lot!. The reason is because Im building a Shiny app that allows to generate any type of classification model using any dataset. So, what I want to include is a verbatimTextOutput where the call appears whether an error happens or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as.call` is your friend. `quote` function name as first list element first.

```
lstParams <- list()
lstParams$name <- quote(gbm::gbm)
lstParams$formula <- as.formula("Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length")                       
lstParams$data <- substitute(iris)
lstParams$distribution <- "bernoulli"
g <- as.call(lstParams)
```

#### Call

```
g
# gbm::gbm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, 
#          data = iris, distribution = "bernoulli")
```

#### Evaluation

```
eval(g)
# gbm::gbm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, 
#          distribution = "bernoulli", data = iris)
# A gradient boosted model with bernoulli loss function.
# 100 iterations were performed.
# There were 2 predictors of which 0 had non-zero influence.
```

You can still use `do.call`.

```
do.call("gbm", as.list(g)[-1])
# A gradient boosted model with bernoulli loss function.
# 100 iterations were performed.
# There were 2 predictors of which 0 had non-zero influence.
```

Comment: This works for `gbm`, but naming the first argument isn't necessary, and in some cases would cause problems, e.g. if you used this approach on the `kernel` function, where `name` is a parameter.

Comment: @user2554330 Disagree, you can't `eval`uate without the name, can we?

Comment: I think you misunderstood.  I'm suggesting changing `lstParams$name <- quote(gbm::gbm)` to `lstParams[[1]] <- quote(gbm::gbm)`.  With that change `eval(g)` is fine.

Comment: @user2554330 aha so you suggest as unnamed first element, that's fair enough

Comment: Yes, so its name can't clash with a parameter name.